# How to loop through array inside template literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a loop inside some template literal code, inside a modal.

So, the result of an Ajax request... I have shortened all the code to keep the line count down.

```
    .done(function (data) {
        var itemsList = $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            '<p>' + item.prod_name + '<p>';
        });
```

Again, shortened modal code.

```
     var modal = `<div class="modal-body">`
       + itemsList +
     `</div>`;
```

All that is outputted is [object object] but if I console.log my data then I get back the proper data.

Comment: Show your actual data variable.  It is probably not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the array into a string:

```js
data=[{prod_name:1},{prod_name:2}];
        var itemsList = $.map(data, function (item, index) {
            return '<p>' + item.prod_name + '<p>';
        }).join('');
        
        console.log(itemsList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use 
`var modal = "<div class="modal-body">" +JSON.stringify(itemList) +"</div>";`

`JSON.stringify(itemList)` would give you the data inside the object.